# Phpunit, expecting a method exactly run two times

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

```
class TestMe
{
    public function method() { }
}
```

test:

```
class TestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testA()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe');
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method');
    }

    public function testB()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe');
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method');
        $stub->method();
    }

    public function testC()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe');
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method');
        $stub->method();
        $stub->method();
    }

    public function testD()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe');
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method');
        $stub->method();
        $stub->method();
        $stub->method();
    }
}
```

testA, testB, testC passes, testD fails only, this is odd.
testA doesnt even call the method, so it shouldve failed - but it passed, why?
testB calls the method ONCE, but we expected TWICE so it shouldve failed - but it passed, why?
testC is OK, no question
testD fails so its OK, no question

maybe the exactly() doesnt work exactly I anticipate. Im using the newest 4.3.4 PhPunit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the method name you want to mock in the `getMock` call.

For obtain the aspected result i modify the Test Class as:

```
class TestTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testA()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe',array('method'));
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method');
    }

    public function testB()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe',array('method'));
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method')->withAnyParameters();
        $stub->method();
    }

    public function testC()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe',array('method'));
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method')->withAnyParameters();
        $stub->method();
        $stub->method();
    }

    public function testD()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMock ('TestMe',array('method'));
        $stub->expects ($this->exactly(2))->method('method')->withAnyParameters();
        $stub->method();
        $stub->method();
        $stub->method();
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
PHPUnit 4.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

There were 3 failures:

1) Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\TestTest::testA
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:method> when invoked 2 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 2 times, actually called 0 times.

2) Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\TestTest::testB
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:method> when invoked 2 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 2 times, actually called 1 times.

3) Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\TestTest::testD
TestMe::method() was not expected to be called more than 2 times.
```

Hope this help